# How to compile tmux 1.7 on CentOS 5.8?

Tags: centos, compiling, tmux

I would like to have tmux 1.7 on my machine with CentOS 5.8 (64 bit).

It requires libevent in version at least 1.4.14b or 2.0.20 and the latest version in `yum` packages for CentOS 5.8 is 1.4.13 .

I know that I need the `libevent-devel` package as well to build `tmux` but I cannot get it anywhere.

Can anyone give me hints how to do this ?

How can I get (build) the devel package ?

Comment: Any update on how you made out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following steps to compile tmux 1.7 on CentOS 5.8:

#### Install developer tools

```
yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install rpm-build gcc
```

#### Setup .rpmmacros file

```
$ cat > /home/<myusername>/.rpmmacros << EOF
%packager Your Name
%vendor Your Orgnazation
%_topdir /home/<myusername>/rpmbuild
%_signature gpg
%_gpg_name Your Packaging Dept
%_gpg_path /home/mockbuild/.gnupg
%dist build_id
%buildroot 
EOF
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you substitute your $HOME path into `<myusername>`.

#### Setup rpmbuild area

```
mkdir -p $HOME/rpmbuild/{BUILD,RPMS/i386,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
```

#### Build libevent 2.x RPM

```
# d/l package
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/levent/files/libevent/libevent-2.0/libevent-2.0.10-stable.tar.gz/download
mv libevent-2.0.10-stable.tar.gz rpmbuild/SOURCES/

# download .spec file
wget http://geekery.altervista.org/specs/libevent2010.spec
mv libevent2010.spec rpmbuild/SPECS

# build RPM
rpmbuild -bb rpmbuild/SPECS/libevent2010.spec
```

#### Install libevent packages

```
cd $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64
rpm -ivh libevent-devel-2.0.10-1build_id.x86_64.rpm libevent-2.0.10-1build_id.x86_64.rpm
```

#### Download tmux SRPM

For this we're going to download the SRPM for Fedora, but extract the contents of it out and reuse it's .spec file to build tmux for CentOS 5.x.

```
cd $HOME/rpmbuild
wget ftp://ftp.muug.mb.ca/mirror/fedora/linux/development/19/source/SRPMS/t/tmux-1.7-2.fc19.src.rpm
mkdir -p temp && cd temp
rpm2cpio ../tmux-1.7-2.fc19.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
mv tmux.spec ../SPECS/ && mv tmux-1.7.tar.gz ../SOURCES/
cd ../SPECS/ && rmdir ../temp/
```

#### Edit tmux.spec

```
vim tmux.spec
```

I ran into several issues with this tmux.spec file. Not sure if it was my setup or not so I made these changes but you may not require them.

```
# Added these lines after the BuildRequires
BuildRoot:      %{buildroot}
Prefix:         /usr

# added DESTDIR=%{buildroot}
make %{?_smp_mflags} LDFLAGS="%{optflags}" DESTDIR=%{buildroot}

# changed this line
%{_bindir}/bin/tmux
# to this line
/usr/bin/tmux
```

Save this file.

#### Building tmux RPM

```
cd $HOME/rpmbuild
rpmbuild -ba SPECS/tmux.spec
rpm -ivh RPM/x86_64/tmux-1.7-2.x86_64.rpm
```

#### prebuilds

Given the number of steps to do this I'm going to do you a favor and provide these RPMs in my yum repository.

- [libevent-2.0.10-1.x86_64.rpm](http://www.lamolabs.org/yum-repos/CentOS/5/x86_64/libevent-2.0.10-1.x86_64.rpm)
- [libevent-devel-2.0.10-1.x86_64.rpm](http://www.lamolabs.org/yum-repos/CentOS/5/x86_64/libevent-devel-2.0.10-1.x86_64.rpm)
- [tmux-1.7-2.x86_64.rpm](http://www.lamolabs.org/yum-repos/CentOS/5/x86_64/tmux-1.7-2.x86_64.rpm)

#### References

- [build libevent and transmission on RHEL/CentOS 5.x](http://geekery.blog.com/2011/05/08/build-libevent-and-transmission-on-rhelcentos-5-x/)
- [Packaging software with RPM, Part 1: Building and distributing packages](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/)
- [How To Extract an RPM Package Without Installing It (rpm extract command)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html)